# Repeated actions. How many

Tags: past-tense

1 I have been watching TV twice this week

2 I had been watching TV twice this week

3 I will have been watching TV twice by the end of this week.

Now, I know that you could say that all these examples are wrong because we don't  use continuous forms when we exactly specify how many. Although we could say "While I was sick she was calling me 5 times a day" here we use a continuous form even though we specify how many it's fine because we show that the action is temporary. Can you think of any context where my examples 1, 2 and 3 are correct or just past coninuous is unique here?

Comment: #2 is probably *never* valid, and for any "normal" context, #3 is pointlessly complex compared to *I **will have watched** TV twice by the end of this week.* Is there *really* any point in explaining some contrived context where #3 might be *preferred*? I kinda doubt it. It might be more useful for you to explain exactly what you want to say, and we'll tell you if your phrasing is valid for the intended sense.

Comment: In reference to #1,  *I have been sleeping in most days this week* is subtly different to *I have slept in most days this week*, but I doubt even most native speakers could explain the difference. I advise you to avoid what's usually *pointless* complexity.

Comment: 3) is fine, the others are not.

Comment: Why is 3 fine? I specify how many " twice". I thought I was obliged to use future perfect simple rather than continuous. The same way as it works with 1 and 2.

Comment: #1 and #2 "I have watched TV twice this week." #3 "I will have watched TV twice by the end of the week." When you use *watching* in the past like that, it is usually some more continuous action, such as "I was / have been watching out for the [rare bird] this week".

Comment: I know that I could say "I have been watching for hours this week" because it's vague. When it is clear then I'm not. I can see some exceptions like the one which I presented with past continuous. I want to know if we have any other exceptions with other continuous tenses.

Comment: ...and it would imply that you are still watching a lot of TV.

Comment: Can you write down exceptions if there are any which makw my exapmles 1 2 3 correct?

Comment: Please see the first comment from FF.

Answer (score 1):

As you state, "have been" indicates the *present perfect continuous*, which means an action that started in the *indefinite past* has come to completion, or *is still in progress*. It's quite normal to use this about watching TV for an unspecified amount of time (eg "*I have been watching a lot of TV this week*") but it just isn't appropriate when you introduce a count of occasions as you have.

The example you gave of 5 phone calls a day is not comparable because it isn't a fixed amount - although there is a number per day, you don't say how many days that went on for, when it started, or when it stopped, so it is *indefinite*.

I can't even think of a convoluted context where any of your examples would be correct. They instantly sound wrong to my native ears. All of them should be either "*I have watched...*", or "*I will have watched...*" in the case of example 3.

Comment: But you agree that my example with past continuous "While I was sick she was calling me 5 times a day" is correct?

Comment: @Bob Yeah it's correct! Because you're speaking in the continuous sense, not about a fixed amount. It was 5 times *each day*. That's why its different from the example you're asking about. If you said "*I have been watching TV twice a day this week*", that would be fine, too. But sadly, all your examples are wrong.

Comment: Yeah I think I get it. Thanks

Comment: @Bob I was scratching my head about the "was calling me 5 times a day," and why it works at all, and I think I put my finger on it: It's a _rate_, like "he was driving 50 miles per hour." You wouldn't say "While I was sick, she was calling me 5 times." It's still an unspecified total.